# How to use WindowBuilder to edit a JPanel in an inner class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I would like to use WindowBuilder in Eclipse to construct Swing GUIs. The JPanels I need to build will be inner classes in a non-GUI wrapper, like so:

```
public class MyWrapper extends MyBaseClass {
  ...
  class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    ...
  }
}
```

So my question is this: can I construct MyPanel using WindowBuilder? If so, how should I set it up?

If anyone is interested, the wrapper is an abstract base class which the plug-ins I am developing for my app must extend; deployment concerns mean that it's not really practical to put the GUIs in a separate JAR either so I pretty much have to do it this way.

My current workflow, which is awful, is to build the GUI in NetBeans and paste the entire generated class into Eclipse where I connect it up to the methods in my wrapper. I am very hopeful that WindowBuilder will let me work more reliably and efficiently if I can trick it into generating code in MyPanel, not MyWrapper.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear why the JPanel must be an inner class. In general, that is not a good idea (you will end up with multiple .class files either way). The JPanel should just be its own top-level class and referenced from your wrapper class (all of which can be in the same jar). WindowBuilder can easily be used to create/edit your JPanel subclasses (including ones originally created with NetBeans), but it will only do so for top-level classes. It won't allow you to create/edit an inner class like this (which is entirely intentional).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but as I said in the question I cannot put the panel in a top level class. I know how it *should* be done, but my reasons for not doing it this way are sound and immutable. Anyway, thanks for confirming that WB can't do this by design; that's good to know.